# App crashes on launch on iOS 6 but working fine on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I developed an app in Xcode 5. Until now I only tested it on a device running iOS 7. I tried running it on another device with iOS 6 but it crashes on launch in the main function without any error message in the console. The deployment target is 6.0 and I've chosen Standard architectures(armv7, armv7s) in the Build Settings.

I also checked the code for methods available only for iOS 7. Could it be that I accidentally skipped one? As for as I know I should get an error message if it doesn't recognise the method.

I'm not a newbie on iOS development, but something is skipping my attention. Do you have any idea what it could be?

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

UPDATE:

This is it... Could it be something in the plist...?

[image]

I finally got to the bottom of this problem thanks to "OC Rickard". Writing 'bt' in the console, this was the output:

- thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x38a8b454 CoreFoundation`CFDictionaryRemoveValue + 12, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  frame #0: 0x38a8b454 CoreFoundation`CFDictionaryRemoveValue + 12
  frame #1: 0x36e58e28 GraphicsServices`RemoveFont + 740
  frame #2: 0x36e58868 GraphicsServices`AddFontsFromCGFontAndPath + 332
  frame #3: 0x36e58660 GraphicsServices`AddFontsFromURLOrPath + 156
  frame #4: 0x36e59e12 GraphicsServices`**Initialize_block_invoke_0 + 378
  frame #5: 0x36e3a4b6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 22
  frame #6: 0x36e403f6 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 42
  frame #7: 0x36e57f7a GraphicsServices`Initialize + 78
  frame #8: 0x36e57fc0 GraphicsServices`GSFontCreateWithName + 56
  frame #9: 0x31c7cfea UIKit`UINewFont + 58
  frame #10: 0x31c7cf9a UIKit`+[UIFont systemFontOfSize:traits:] + 18
  frame #11: 0x31fa608c UIKit`-[UIStatusBarServiceItemView _contentsImageFromString:withWidth:letterSpacing:forStyle:] + 124
  frame #12: 0x31cd888a UIKit`-[UIStatusBarServiceItemView _serviceContentsImageForStyle:] + 362
  frame #13: 0x31cd84ac UIKit`-[UIStatusBarServiceItemView updateContentsAndWidth] + 140
  frame #14: 0x31cd823e UIKit`-[UIStatusBarItemView initWithItem:data:actions:style:] + 306
  frame #15: 0x31cd7f90 UIKit`-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _createViewForItem:withData:actions:] + 108
  frame #16: 0x31c877de UIKit`-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _prepareEnabledItemType:withEnabledItems:withData:actions:itemAppearing:itemDisappearing:] + 134
  frame #17: 0x31c8770e UIKit`-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager prepareEnabledItems:withData:actions:] + 82
  frame #18: 0x31f9e910 UIKit`-[UIStatusBarForegroundView _setStatusBarData:actions:animated:] + 168
  frame #19: 0x31c87662 UIKit`-[UIStatusBarForegroundView setStatusBarData:actions:animated:] + 722
  frame #20: 0x31cd7516 UIKit`-[UIStatusBar _prepareToSetStyle:animation:] + 794
  frame #21: 0x31c8978e UIKit`-[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animationParameters:] + 558
  frame #22: 0x31c894a8 UIKit`-[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animated:] + 84
  frame #23: 0x31cd2f6e UIKit`-[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:] + 258
  frame #24: 0x31cd2736 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 430
  frame #25: 0x31c7ac38 UIKit`-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1004
  frame #26: 0x31c7a6cc UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
  frame #27: 0x31c7a11a UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
  frame #28: 0x36e5d5a2 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 590
  frame #29: 0x36e5d1d2 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 34
  frame #30: 0x38b1d172 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 34
  frame #31: 0x38b1d116 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
  frame #32: 0x38b1bf98 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1384
  frame #33: 0x38a8eebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
  frame #34: 0x38a8ed48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
  frame #35: 0x31cd147c UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 668
  frame #36: 0x31cce2f8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1120
  frame #37: 0x00085f96 iSpyLove`main(argc=1, argv=0x2fd98d20) + 110 at main.m:16
  frame #38: 0x362fab20 libdyld.dylib`start + 4

I had a font declared in the plist file which had .dfont extension. Apparently iOS 6 didn't like this. Thank you "OC Rickard", and thanks to all of you guys for taking interest in my problem.

Comment: Did you set an exception breakpoint to see where it's crashing?

Comment: Without the actual crash report it is impossible to know.

Comment: More then likely you calling a method that is in the iOS 7 API but not in the iOS 6. Like `kerni` has said without the crash report we can't tell you how to solve this. But I bet it is `unrecognized selector` error, am I right?

Comment: I have an exception breakpoint set. I don't get any crash report. It sends me to the main function when it crashes...

Comment: There must be something. It doesn't just crash and tell you nothing, just like if an exception breakpoint is set it will crash on the line. When it makes it to the main function this is just saying we crashed but you haven't set a us up to break on the crash so we'll go here and leave you to it. There will be a crash report somewhere.

Comment: I've updated my post with a screenshot..

Comment: OK, can you please run this command in your lldb window (the one at the bottom of your screen that has (lldb) in blue in it): 'bt'.  Paste result here.

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is being cause by you trying to remove an object from an `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSDictionary` that doesn't exist. Note in the navigation bar at the left hand side the  `CFDictionaryRemoveValue` this says it is crashing when running this. If you have set a exception breakpoint correctly this will break at the line where you are trying to do the remove. Are you doing anything with `Dictionaries` like this?

Comment: Drag the slider on the lower-left all the way to the right, so you can see all the relevant stack frames, not just the top one.

Comment: Are you using an external framework? I had a very similar problem. App was running ok on iOS6 but crashed without logs on iOS7. Turned out the Pixate framework was causing this. We removed it and then it all worked fine.

Comment: Start the app without the debugger attached on a device. Then use the organizer to get the crash report. Comment code until it doesn't crash any more. Then post the crash report and code that caused the crash.

Comment: Thank you OC Rickard!! Typing 'bt' helped me figure out what the problem was. Thanks to all of you guys for your interest in my problem.